# JPA unidirectional one-to-many relationship persist

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, cascade

I'm trying to persist 3 entities with one-to-many relationship but I cannot get it right.
This is what I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "pk_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private long personId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
    private List<Phone> phones;
}


@Entity
@IdClass(PersonBrandId.class)
@Table(name = "tb_person_phone")
public class Phone {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "retailer_id")
     private long personId;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "brand_code")
     private String brandCode;

     @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
     @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "brand_code", referencedColumnName = "brand_code", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
     List<Mobile> mobiles;

     ...other fields...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_mobile")
public class Mobile {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq2", sequenceName = "pk_seq2", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq2")
    @Column(name="mobile_id")
    private long mobileId;

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private long personId;

    ...other fields...
}
```

So, what I'm trying to reach is to persist Person only and, because the cascade, Phone and Mobile will be persisted automatically.
Example:

```
Person person = new Person();
Phone phone = new Phone();
Mobile mobile = new Mobile();
phone.getMobiles().add(mobile);
person.getPhones().add(phone);

em.persist(person);
```

The problem is that I get an error saying the tb_person_phone.person_id cannot be null.

The relation is unidirectional so I didn't add the ManyToOne side.

In order to answer some comment:

1. I am using JPA only
2. the relation is the following:

   Person can have multiple Phone.

   Phone has composite primary key:

   ```
      - person_id in Person

      - brand_code in Brand (a table with a list of brands)
   ```

   Mobile has primary key: mobile_id

   ```
     has two FK:

      - person_id and brand_code both referencing the table Phone
   ```

SQL to generate the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "TB_PERSON"
(   "PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PERSON_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "PERSON_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID")
);


CREATE TABLE "TB_PERSON_PHONE" 
(   "PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BRAND_CODE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ATTR1" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "ATTR2" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 CONSTRAINT "PERSON_PHONE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID", "BRAND_CODE")
 FOREIGN KEY ("PERSON_ID")
  REFERENCES "TB_PERSON" ("PERSON_ID") ENABLE, 
 FOREIGN KEY ("BRAND_CODE")
  REFERENCES "TB_BRAND" ("BRAND_CODE") ENABLE
);


CREATE TABLE "TB_MOBILE" 
(   "MOBILE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"BRAND_CODE" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"NUMBER" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ATTR1" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"ATTR2" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 CONSTRAINT "MOBILE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MOBILE_ID"),
 CONSTRAINT "MOBILE_UQ" UNIQUE ("NUMBER", "PERSON_ID", "BRAND_CODE")
 USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MOBILE_UQ_IDX" ON "TB_MOBILE" ("NUMBER",       "PERSON_ID", "BRAND_CODE"),
 FOREIGN KEY ("PERSON_ID", "BRAND_CODE")
  REFERENCES "TB_PERSON_PHONE" ("PERSON_ID", "BRAND_CODE") ENABLE
 );
```

Comment: Are you using Hibernate and JPA or only JPA?

Comment: How are you imagining personId and brandCode get set in Phone? From a modelling perspective  aren't persons <-> phones in a many to many relationship and a phone should have a brand??

Comment: As I noted in my previous comment your code is fundamentally flawed. The two ID fields in Phone cannot be magically set.  Apart from that I do not understand your model or your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Set `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` for Primary keys of both Mobile and Phone entities.

Comment: Can you share the sql queries for those three tables will be easy for me to debug. @user1341300

Comment: I added the sql to generate the tables

Answer (score 0):

You are using person id as a identifier in Phone class

```
@Id
 @Column(name = "retailer_id")
 private long personId;
```

place another column as Id and add some generation id strategy or

```
 Person person = new Person();

 em.persist(person); //<

 Phone phone = new Phone();
 Mobile mobile = new Mobile();
 phone.getMobiles().add(mobile);
 person.getPhones().add(phone);

 phone.setPersonId(person.getId()); // <

 em.persist(person);
```

Comment: This means that I have to persist the Person first and then call the em again